# Can a GIF have a CMYK profile?

Tags: images, cmyk, gif, color-profile

While working on an InDesign script that checks the links used in a file I decided to check what color profile has been used on images so I can output it to a log for the user however when I write my conditional to check if a link is a GIF I was unsure if a GIF could actually have a CMYK profile.  When I research [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF):

> The format supports up to 8 bits per pixel for each image, allowing a
>   single image to reference its own palette of up to 256 different
>   colors chosen from the 24-bit RGB color space. It also supports
>   animations and allows a separate palette of up to 256 colors for each
>   frame. These palette limitations make the GIF format less suitable for
>   reproducing color photographs and other images with continuous color,
>   but it is well-suited for simpler images such as graphics or logos
>   with solid areas of color.

It mentions RGB **only** but it doesn't mention if a CMYK profile can be supported.  So, can a GIF support a CMYK profile?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no mention of CMYK in the [GIF specification](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt), and it only supports color triplets. Take a peek at the syntax for color tables given by the spec:

```
      7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0        Field Name                    Type
     +===============+
  0  |               |       Red 0                         Byte
     +-             -+
  1  |               |       Green 0                       Byte
     +-             -+
  2  |               |       Blue 0                        Byte
     +-             -+
  3  |               |       Red 1                         Byte
     +-             -+
     |               |       Green 1                       Byte
     +-             -+
 up  |               |
     +-   . . . .   -+       ...
 to  |               |
     +-             -+
     |               |       Green 255                     Byte
     +-             -+
767  |               |       Blue 255                      Byte
     +===============+
```

Since CMYK values would require color quadruplets, any parser that follows the spec wouldn't know what to do with a "CMYK GIF" even if you shoehorned the values in.

Answer (score 12):

The short answer is no, a GIF can't support a CMYK profile.

A CMYK profile is a series off curves that map the percentage value of each separation to a target. GIF images are saved as INDEXED COLOUR, which then references an RGB value for each colour. While CMYK values could be derived from the RGB values (the RGB gamut is wider than the CMYK gamut so some colours would have to be approximated), there would not be a continuous, complete 'curve' of colour values so the profile would not have the necessary freedom to adjust.

If you are supplied with GIFs or RGB files or anything other than CMYK for print work then the best route is to convert them to CMYK and issue a proof for approval. Sometimes all will be well, sometimes it will be a disaster.

*Also, I take issue with the suggestion that the 'correct' pronunciation is with a soft g (as in sounds like JIF), the G in GIF stands for Graphic, with a hard G, so GIF should be pronounced with a G that sounds like the G in Graphic. I don't care what anybody (including the inventors of the format) say.*

Comment: I once heard someone say "who ever heard of a {GER-affe}. ergo Jif." I pointed out that Jrafic Interchange Format is equally nonsensical.

Comment: Giraffic Interchange Format? I'm just being silly now.

Comment: Star Wars pun: **G**alactic **I**mperial **F**orce cannot support the **R**ough **G**oazon **B**adlands

Comment: @Yorik: For that matter, do people exchange jifts at Christmas time?

Comment: Is that a goke? I don't jet it.

Comment: "I don't care what anybody (including the inventors of the format) say." Not just the inventor of the format, but the man who came up with the actual name itself, and declared its correct pronunciation. The G comes from graphics, but it's pronounced JIF because it was at the time a FASTER file format to retrieve, available in a jiffy.

Comment: @barbecue but its not particulary jiffy. Thing is inventors and discoverers get to propose a name, does not mean we have to accept it. Things change all the time...

Comment: @joojaa Not sure what you mean by "not particularly jiffy." We are talking dialup modem speeds, where it could take several MINUTES to retrieve a single image. GIF provided a huge speed increase over other formats from the time (like TGA.) And while you may be right that people can choose to pronounce it however they want, claiming the person who literally invented the technology AND coined the name has no say in the matter is pretty ridiculous.

Comment: @barbecue even people who discover new species, who really deserve a say, sometimes get overturned. Life sucks.

Comment: @joojaa you young whippersnappers with your new-fangled ways of saying things need to get off my lawn ;)

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ Wouldn't that be **G**alactic **I**mperial **F**orce can't support **C**3-droids **Y**oda **M**ight **K**ill?